# How to run Powershell script on multiple Subscriptions Using Az PowerShell Command

Tags: azure, powershell

I have multiple azure tenants, each having multiple subscriptions, and I have to run a single PowerShell script for all my subscriptions.

This can be achieved using `Azure CLI`, and it works perfectly.

I use `Azure CLI` as below;

```
$az_account = (az account list --query "[].[name]" -o tsv)
foreach ($account in $az_account) {
    az account set --name $account
    #<RUN SCRIPTS HERE>#
}
```

But in some situations, I have to use the `Az PowerShell` command instead of `Azure CLI`.

So could anyone help me

1. How to run `Az PowerShell` commands for multiple subscriptions
2. Or the `Az PowerShell` profile file path ( same as `Azure CLI` which is `C:\Users\%USER\.Azure\azureProfile.json` ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolution**

After a couple of tries, finally found some methods to solve my issue. posting the same here might be helpful for someone.

You can connect all the subscriptions using the below commands

```
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant "xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxx" -Subscription "xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxx"
```

To List all the connected subscriptions

```
Get-AzContext -ListAvailable | Select-Object Name, Subscription, Tenant
```

[image]

If you want to rename to a friendly Name,

```
Rename-AzContext -SourceName "Azure subscription 1 (xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx) - xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx - jawad@xyz.com" -TargetName "MySubscription"
```

To save these profiles to file,

```
Save-AzContext -Path "C:\Users\jawad\Downloads\AzpwshProfile.json"
```

You can import any time these profiles using the below command, (test first clear the profile `Clear-AzContext -Force`)

```
Import-AzContext -Path "C:\Users\jawad\Downloads\AzpwshProfile.json"
```

Now you easily use `for` loop to set the subscriptions, for example

```
$acc = (Get-AzContext -ListAvailable | Select-Object Name)
foreach ($account in $acc) {
>> Select-AzContext $account.Name
>> Get-AzVM | Export-Csv -Path "inventory.csv"
>> }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How to run  `Az PowerShell`  commands for multiple subscriptions

You can use the below PowerShell Scripts to run the multiple subscription PowerShell commands.

```
# Get the Subscription Details using Get-AzSubscription Command
Get-AzSubscription | ForEach-Object {
    # Set the context Details using Set-AzContext Command which is equalent to the az account set CLI Command
    $_ | Set-AzContext
    $subscriptionName = $_.Name
      #<RUN YOUR SCRIPTS HERE>#

}
```

[image]

> 2. Or the  `Az PowerShell`  profile file path ( same as  `Azure CLI`  which is  `C:\Users\%USER\.Azure\azureProfile.json`  ).

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.2) for profile file path location

Comment: Thanks @DelliganeshS-MT, also can you support me on how to add multiple tenant subscriptions, I couldn't more than 2 using  `Connect-AzAccount -TenantId 'xxxx-xxx-xx-xxx'`

Comment: same way you can fetch the tenant Ids. But you can connect to azure with only one subscription.